# Monitor modem speed and transfer volumes in OS X

Tags: macos, software-rec, modem, 3g

I've got Nokia CS-17 internet stick and looking for a simple utility that would show me my connection speed and transfer volumes while i'm connected, ideally directly in the menu bar.

I don't want to use the utility provided by the vendor. I'm using Mac OSX 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using [Menu Meter](http://www.ragingmenace.com/software/menumeters/index.html).

> MenuMeters is a set of CPU, memory, disk, and network monitoring tools
>   for Mac OS X. Although there are numerous other programs which do the
>   same thing, none had quite the feature set I was looking for. Most
>   were windows that sat in a corner or on the desktop, which are
>   inevitably obscured by document windows on a laptop's small screen.
>   Those monitors which used the menubar mostly used the NSStatusItem
>   API, which has the annoying tendency to totally reorder my menubar on
>   every login.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What results does that give, every image I look at from that program just shows settings and no graphs or data.

Comment: I added a screen shot and linked to the original developer homepage. Maximus, you could take a look at [How to Answer](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-answer) and try to make your answers really stand out! /cc @Ivo

Comment: it will give you one or multiple icons in your menu bar with will display network/ IO/ processor /memory usage. when clicking on the icon you'll get detail. it sets up in the pref panel so it's also easy to install and configure